# Make Mysql database that exists manageable with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have a Mysql database on my server.  I can get into it via the command line, so it does exist.  However, when I go into cpanel and open up phpmyadmin, it is not there.

What do you have to do to make an existing database manageable with phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database created using the root? if so you must set user permissions to cPanel in WHM.

Answer (score 0):

If the database was directly created from MySQL server or somehow it is not showing in cPanel -> phpMyAdmin, you can use "Database Map Tool" from WHM to map the database to your cPanel user.